# How to represent an unknown Object in DTO in c# class

Tags: c#, dto

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am given third party url with these model:

Request:

```
{
 "username": to_be_shared,
 "password": to_be_shared
 
}
```

Response:

```
{
 "response_code": "00",
 "response_description": "Success"
 "data": {...},
 "size": 0,
 "access_token": "access_token",
 "refresh_token": "refresh_token",
 "expires_in": "18000000",
 "token_type": "BEARER"
}
```

In the DTO, I have represented Request as:

```
public class OAuthLoginRequest
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

}
```

and response as:

```
public class OAuthLoginResponse
{
    public string response_code { get; set; }
    public string response_description { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public string expires_in { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
}
```

If you observe, in the **OAuthLoginResponse**, I didn't add **"data": {...},**  as given in Response since the detail not given.

How do I represent this (data) in the DTO?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `dynamic` or `Dictionary<string,object>` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I don't understand. Kindly assist. How do I represent it in my DTO based on my scenario?  Thanks

Comment: It's JSON, and the contents of data is between brackets, that means it's an object. JSON objects are a collection of key-value pairs. .NET can model- bind that to a dictionary. But the values can be many types (even aan embedded object, i.e. a new dictionary). Hence the `object` type, which you need to detect during runtime.

Comment: In response to your comment below: that's not how stack overflow works. We are not here to solve your problems for you. We can help you with coding issues, but you have to put in the elbow grease yourself. Panagiotis told you what type you could use for model binding `data`. Do the rest of the research yourself, so you learn. Use a debugger of you have to.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to use Generics class OAuthLoginResponse where T: class and fill property public T Data {get;set;}

When your server returns ActionResult(OAuthLoginResponse response) it shows all data from your T Data field don't matter what type of T is used

Comment: Ok, and how would you instantiate the generic class/ method? Read the question well

Comment: @JHBonarius - Kindly use my code to represent the solution. Thanks

Comment: @Ikomarovleonid - Can you represent the concept from my code.. I'm following the explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OAuthLoginResponse
{
   ...
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> data{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```